# PETSC DMDA vec values are assigned to wrang place

Tags: c++, petsc

I recently started learning PETSc and encountered a problem while trying to accomplish  some simple task. What is wrong  with this code:

```
static char help[] = "Test  2d DMDAs Vecs.\n\n";
#include <petscdm.h>
#include <petscdmda.h>
#include <petscsys.h>
PetscReal process_value(int rank, int i) {
    return i*PetscPowScalar(10,rank*2);
}
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
  PetscErrorCode   ierr;
  PetscMPIInt      rank;
  PetscInt         M = -5,N = -3;
  DM               da;
  Vec              local,global;
  ierr = PetscInitialize(&argc,&argv,(char*)0,help);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr  = MPI_Comm_rank(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&rank);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMDACreate2d(PETSC_COMM_WORLD , DM_BOUNDARY_NONE , DM_BOUNDARY_NONE 
    , DMDA_STENCIL_BOX , M , N , PETSC_DECIDE, PETSC_DECIDE
    ,   1 , 1 , NULL ,  NULL ,  &da); CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMCreateGlobalVector(da,&global);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMCreateLocalVector(da,&local);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  {
      PetscInt       v,i, j,   xm, ym, xs, ys;
      PetscScalar    **array;
      ierr = DMDAGetCorners(da, &xs, &ys, 0, &xm, &ym, 0); CHKERRQ(ierr);
      PetscSynchronizedPrintf(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,"%d:xs=%d\txm=%d\tys=%d\tym=%d\n",rank,xs,xm,ys,ym);
      PetscSynchronizedFlush(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,PETSC_STDOUT);
      ierr = DMDAVecGetArray(da, global, &array); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    v=0;
      for (j = ys; j < ys + ym; j++) {
      for (i = xs; i < xs + xm; i++) {
          array[j][i] = process_value(rank,v+=1);
      }
      }
    ierr = DMDAVecRestoreArray(da, global, &array); CHKERRQ(ierr);
  }
    ierr = VecView(global,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecDestroy(&local);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecDestroy(&global);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMDestroy(&da);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFinalize();
  return 0;
}
```

It fills small array with quantities labeled by  process rank.
After successful compilation and linking it gives the following result:

```
> mpiexec -n 2 ./problem  
0:xs=0  xm=3    ys=0    ym=3
1:xs=3  xm=2    ys=0    ym=3
Vec Object: 2 MPI processes
  type: mpi
Vec Object:Vec_0x84000004_0 2 MPI processes
  type: mpi
Process [0]
1.
2.
3.
100.
200.
4.
5.
6.
300.
Process [1]
400.
7.
8.
9.
500.
600.
>
```

VecView shows  that processes have written to places that  belong to other process. Where is an error? DMDAVecGetArray/DMDAVecRestoreArray  give wrong array or VecView is not suitable to view Vec obtained from DM object ?

Answer (score 1):

`DMDAVecGetArray()` and `DMDAVecRestoreArray()` work perfectly fine. Indeed, you are dealing with a feature of `VecView()` described in the [mailing list of petsc](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/petsc-users/2011-March/008302.html) a few years ago.

***As is, `VecView()` prints the vector from the DMDA using the natural ordering.***

```
proc0   proc1
1  2  | 3  4
5  6  | 7  8
___________
9  10 | 11 12
13 14 | 15 16
proc2   proc3
```

The difference between the natural ordering and Petsc's ordering is underlined in the [documentation of Petsc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manual.pdf), in section 2.5 about structured grids. Here is what Petsc's ordering looks like:

```
proc0   proc1
1  2  | 5  6
3  4  | 7  8
___________
9  10 | 13 14
11 12 | 15 16
proc2   proc3
```

As signaled in the thread [VecView doesn't work properly with DA global vectors](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/petsc-users/2011-March/008302.html), ***it is still possible to print the vector using Petsc's ordering by using:***

```
PetscViewerPushFormat(PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD,PETSC_VIEWER_NATIVE);
VecView(global,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);
PetscViewerPopFormat(PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);
```

Let's take a closer look to the source of Petsc to see how it works. The `VecView()` operation for DMDA vector is overloaded as the `DMCreateGlobalVector_DA()` function is called (see [dadist.c](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/src/dm/impls/da/dadist.c.html)): the new method is `VecView_MPI_DA()` in [gr2.c](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/src/dm/impls/da/gr2.c.html). Unsurprisingly, it calls a function `DMDACreateNaturalVector()` and later prints the natural vector using the native `VecView()`. If the format `PETSC_VIEWER_NATIVE` is used, the [vector interface](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/src/vec/vec/interface/vector.c.html) calls the operation `*vec->ops->viewnative`, which likely points to the native `VecView()` function `VecView_MPI_ASCII()` in [pdvec.c](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/src/vec/vec/impls/mpi/pdvec.c.html). This explains the strange ( but very practical! ) behavior of VecView for DMDA vectors.

If you wish to keep the natural ordering, you can revome the meaningless `Process[0]...Process[3]` that get printed by using:

```
PetscViewerPushFormat(PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD, PETSC_VIEWER_ASCII_COMMON);
```